# Controlling html table column widths with different rules for different columns

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 5 columns.

The first column should be the width of its widest content.

The third, fourth, and fifth columns should be a fixed number of pixels wide.

The second column should fill the remaining width. The contents will often overflow, but I don't want that to affect the width of the column (I'll do an overflow hidden with ellipsis on that column.)

What I have so far is:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
th:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(4), th:nth-child(5) {
    width: 30px;
}
th:nth-child(2) {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
th:nth-child(1) {
    /* width: ????? */
}
```

What this does is successfully make the first two columns the same width. That is, split the remaining space.

How do I specify for the first column "take the exact amount of space you need to display all your contents"? It would do that if I didn't specify "table-layout: fixed", but then I couldn't control the other columns.

Comment: as a workaround created a table inside your third column to hold the rest three columns. check the [codepen](http://codepen.io/gaus06techian/pen/WxjLPq) link. does it help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using datatable for sorting, though, so I need the html to be one normal table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd love to find a pure css way to do this, but I ended up using javascript:

```
<!-- wrap the text to measure in a span and measure the width of the span -->
<table id="my-table">
    <tr><th>First</th> etc... </tr>
    <tr><td><span class="name-text">Adam</span></td>etc...</tr>
    etc...
</table>

var names = $("#my-table").find(".name-text");
var width = 0;
names.each(function(i, name) {
    var w = parseInt($(name).width());
    width = Math.max(width, w);
});

var th = $("#my-table").find("th:nth-child(1)");
th.css({ width: (width + 10) + "px" });
```