# First column of table as wide as it needs to be, other columns equal width

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table where the first column is the product name and a variable number of other columns are the sales data (between 2 and five quarters depending on the product)

I am trying to style it so that the the whole table is 95% of the width of the page, and the first column width is as wide as it needs to be to display the product name without word wrap (though I also want a `max-width` of 30%). Subsequent columns I want to be equal sized and fill the available width of the table.

I have tried layout fixed and auto for the table, and over-riding the style on the first column using `table > thead > tr > th:first-child {` but not found the right combination to solve this.

Needs to be using tables rather than 'pure' CSS as it's being consumed by a template engine which does rending logic based on `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements, and because it's a template I'd prefer to not have to rely on injecting fixed values (eg calculations based on the number of columns, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155380/controlling-html-table-column-widths-with-different-rules-for-different-columns)) though if needs be I can

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 95%;
            border: 1px solid;
        }
        table>tbody>tr>th {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Q1</th>
                <th>Q2</th>
                <th>Q3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Example Product One</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Example product two</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Example Three</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>2000</td>
                <td>3000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and whatever CSS you have tried to implement?

Comment: Do you consider using Bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap - no. Difficult to add other dependencies with the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want wrapping, then you can always use `white-space:nowrap`.

> though I also want a max-width of 30%

It depends how many columns you have and what is the largest text in your first column.

```css
.firstColumnNowrap {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 95%;
}
.firstColumnNowrap thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.firstColumnNowrap tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.firstColumnNowrap thead tr th:first-child, .firstColumnNowrap tbody tr td:first-child {
  white-space:nowrap
}
.firstColumnNowrap thead tr th:not(:first-child), .firstColumnNowrap tbody tr td:not(:first-child) {
  max-width:30%;
}
```

```html
<table class="firstColumnNowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Born</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>I have an HTML table where the first column</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>6'11"</td>
            <td>08-13-1990</td>
            <td>$4,917,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>I have an HTML table where the first column is the product name</td>
            <td>PG</td>
            <td>5'9"</td>
            <td>02-07-1989</td>
            <td>$473,604</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ben McLemore</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td>6'5"</td>
            <td>02-11-1993</td>
            <td>$2,895,960</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Marcus Thornton</td>
            <td>SG</td>
            <td>6'4"</td>
            <td>05-05-1987</td>
            <td>$7,000,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jason Thompson</td>
            <td>PF</td>
            <td>6'11"</td>
            <td>06-21-1986</td>
            <td>$3,001,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: works perfectly, but with one minor weirdness... if one of the columns has a shorter name than others (eg `<tr><th>Product<th>Quarter One 2019<th>Quarter Two 2019<th>Total</tr>` then that shorter named column ends up smaller. Experimenting to see if I can fake a longer name with &nbsp; ...

Comment: If you want other columns to be equal sized except the first one, then you need to use JS/jQuery. I don't know if you are using any.

Answer (score 0):

from comments/answers here, it looks like there isn't a 'pure' CSS version.
as I didn't want to include any dependancies (jQuery or Bootstrap) I ended up writing some javascript to address this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: auto;
}
table td {
    text-align: right;
}
.sasha {
    text-align: left;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sasha">QQ</th>
                <th class="diesel">Quarter One 2019</th>
                <th class="diesel">Quarter Two 2019</th>
                <th class="diesel">Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="sasha">Example Product One</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sasha">Example product two</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sasha">Example Three</td>
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>2000</td>
                <td>3000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <script>
        var table = document.getElementById("mytable")

        var sashas = table.getElementsByClassName("sasha")
        var diesels = table.getElementsByClassName("diesel")
        var sashawidth = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < sashas.length; i++) {
            w = parseInt(sashas[i].clientWidth);
            sashawidth = Math.max(sashawidth, w);
        }

        // now resize table to 100%
        table.style.width = "100%"
        var tablewidth = parseInt(table.clientWidth);
        // reset table sizing
        table.style.width = "auto"

        // cap first column width at 25%
        if (sashawidth > tablewidth * .25) {
            sashawidth = tablewidth * .25
        }

        // calculate width of table, minus first column, divide by "diesels"
        nw = (tablewidth - sashawidth) / diesels.length

        // set first col width (in case we capped it)
        sashas[0].style.width = sashawidth + "px"
        // and set diesels to be their new width
        for (let i = 0; i < diesels.length; i++) {
            diesels[i].style.width = nw-20 + "px" // allows for a little padding
            diesels[i].style.background = "blue"
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>

</html>
```